# Xamarin.Forms back button refresh with Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using **Prism** Navigation Service, with **MasterDetailPage** & **NavigationPage**.

In Android, when I push the OS back button, it doesn't call the **OnNavigatedTo** method of my ViewModel, that implements the **INavigationAware** interface.

I think it's the expected behavior, but how can I refresh the page in a MVVM\Prism way?

Comment: are you trying to capture the navigation back back button pressed or the hardware back button present on android devices?

Comment: @LucasMouraVeloso Do you know how to do it?

Comment: If you want to capture the HARDWARE back button present on Android devices, the event you want is OnBackButtonPressed. Just override it and do your view model processing.

Reference: [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in [Prism for Xamarin.Forms 6.3pre1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Forms/6.3.0-pre1).

Release Notes: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes-6.3.0-Pre1

Issue fixed: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/744